# Smooth transition using CSS and Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, transition

I am using jQuery to change the size of a `header` element on a fixed header depending on scroll location. I have gotten my code to make the change as I want but the change is abrupt rather than smooth. I realize I need to use the `transition` property in CSS but am unable to figure out where or how to do it. A little help would be appreciated.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
    $('.bg').addClass('show')
    $('#headerTitle').css("font-size", "1.5em");
  } else {
    $('.bg').removeClass('show')
    $('#headerTitle').css('font-size', "2em")
  };
});

$('.scroll').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.transition {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.show {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.5em;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#headerTitle {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="bg transition">
  <p style="width: 60%; margin-left: 20%; border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF; padding-bottom: 1em;">
    <span id="headerTitle">Joe Blow</span>
  </p>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `transition` properties in header style:

```
#headerTitle {
font-size: 2em;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks. I knew I needed to add the transition property somewhere, but was not sure where.